# Why can't my Python code load *.SO files when running in a IPython Notebook on Linux?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, jupyter-notebook

I have some Python code, which loads a DLL/SO, via the ctypes.CDLL() function.
It runs fine when run under python/ipython, from the command prompt on all 3 OSes:

- Windows 7 Pro
- Mac OS X
- Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)

It also runs fine in a IPython Notebook, under Windows and Mac OS X.
However, it does NOT work in a IPython Notebook, under Linux. It gives this error:

`OSError: example_tx_x86_amd64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The funny thing is: the *.SO file doesn't show up in the directory listing shown in the *Home* tab of the browser (i.e. - the one from which you select/launch your desired notebook file), either! (All other files in the directory appear there.)

This seems awfully suspicious to me. It's almost as if *.SO files are made invisible to the IPython Notebook Server, for security reasons, but only under Linux! I checked all the Notebook Server options available, but didn't see anything apropos.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks!

Code and backtrace, as requested:

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot   as plt
from numpy      import array
from pyibisami  import amimodel as ami

gTxDLLName   = "example_tx_x86_amd64.so"
gBitRate     = 10.e9
gSampsPerBit = 32
gNumBits     = 100

bit_time         = 1. / gBitRate
sample_interval  = bit_time / gSampsPerBit
row_size         = gNumBits * gSampsPerBit
channel_response = array([0.0, 1.0 / bit_time,])
channel_response.resize(row_size)

my_tx   = ami.AMIModel(gTxDLLName)
tx_init = ami.AMIModelInitializer({'root_name' : "example_tx",
                                   'tx_tap_nm1' : 10,
                                  })
tx_init.bit_time         = bit_time
tx_init.sample_interval  = sample_interval
tx_init.channel_response = channel_response
my_tx.initialize(tx_init)

print "Message from model:"
print "\t", my_tx.msg
print "Parameter string from model:"
print "\t", my_tx.ami_params_out
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        15 channel_response.resize(row_size)
>        16 
>   ---> 17 my_tx   = ami.AMIModel(gTxDLLName)
>        18 tx_init = ami.AMIModelInitializer({'root_name' : "example_tx",
>        19                                    'tx_tap_nm1' : 10,
>
> /home/dbanas/prj/PyAMI/pyibisami/amimodel.pyc in **init**(self,
>   filename)
>       214         " Load the dll and bind the 3 AMI functions."
>       215 
>   --> 216         my_dll = CDLL(filename)
>       217         self._amiInit = my_dll.AMI_Init
>       218         try:
>
> /home/dbanas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ctypes/**init**.pyc in
>   **init**(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
>       363 
>       364         if handle is None:
>   --> 365             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>       366         else:
>       367             self._handle = handle
>
> OSError: example_tx_x86_amd64.so: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

Comment: And where is your code? Can we see a full traceback please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry about the delay in responding.I've edited the original post with code and backtrace, as requested.